# codeigniter: stripping out commas and dollar signs in a callback?

Tags: php, codeigniter

During form validation, I want to be able to take an inputed value like '$5,000' and strip out the comma and dollar sign, returning a value like '5000'. So, I created a callback function that looks like this:

```
function convert_to_number($value)
{
    $result = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $value);
    return $result;
}
```

The strange thing is, instead of stripping out the dollar sign or comma, it just deletes it and every character after it (so that a $5,000 value returns 0, or 5,000 returns 5).

I've also tried the following variant:

```
function convert_to_number($value)
{
    $result = str_replace("$", "", $value);
    $result = str_replace(",", "", $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Same thing happens. It's just boggling my mind. Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: your first code is working fine for me

Comment: hows you doing validation with this function? Share your validation part also.

Comment: `var_dump(preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', '$5,000'));` proves that your _actual_ problem is not what you _think_ it is.

Comment: I have all of the form validation rules in an array. The relevant section for this value is this: `array( 'field'   => 'quote', 'label'   => 'Quote', 'rules'   => 'callback_convert_to_number|numeric'),`

Comment: And, yes, I tested that line of code independently -- and it worked fine -- which is why I'm confused as to why the value that ends up in the database is off.

Comment: I just discovered something -- I took out the validation rule altogether to see what happens, and it STILL deletes any characters after the dollar signs and commas. So it's doing this BEFORE the form validation, I'm guessing (before the callback rule has a chance to clean up the value)?

Answer (score 0):

don't return result try to send actual value back, use result for validation,

```
function convert_to_number($value)
{
    $result = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $value);
    return $value;
}
```